# функциональная разница между экземпляром и объектом, созданным не через __init__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

зачем нужен метод `__init__` вместе в `class`-ом?

Comment: А в учебнике что написано?

Comment: А как вы ещё передадите объекту некие параметры сразу при создании экземпляра, если не через `init`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**`self`**

Слово `self`  используется для обозначения экземпляра класса.
Используя ключевое слово `self`, мы получаем доступ к атрибутам и методам класса в Python.

**`__init__ method`**

`__init__` - это метод в классах Python.
В объектно-ориентированной терминологии он называется конструктором.
Этот метод вызывается, когда объект создается из класса,
и позволяет классу инициализировать атрибуты класса.

```
# Узнайте стоимость прямоугольного поля

class Rectangle:
   def __init__(self, length, breadth, unit_cost=0):
       self.length = length
       self.breadth = breadth
       self.unit_cost = unit_cost
       
   def get_area(self):
       return self.length * self.breadth
       
   def calculate_cost(self):
       area = self.get_area()
       return area * self.unit_cost
       
       
# breadth = 120, length = 160, 1 sq unit cost = 2000 руб.
rectangle = Rectangle(160, 120, 2000)
print(f"Площадь прямоугольника: {rectangle.get_area()}")
```

Answer (score 4):

Магический метод `__init__` запускается при создании экземпляра класса. Пример:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        print('Hello, world!')

a = A()
```

out:

```
Hello, world!
```

Answer (score 2):

`__init__` вызывается уже после создания экземпляра класса, а не во время, в примере ниже видно что сначала выполнится print(1, ob), и лишь затем print(2, self), причем объект экземпляра класса создан уже до вызова `__init__`, и затем просто передается ему в аргумента в self

```
class A():
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        ob = super().__new__(cls)
        print(1, ob)
        return ob

    def __init__(self):
        print(2, self)

a = A()

# 1 <__main__.A object at 0x000002487C6CD2E0>
# 2 <__main__.A object at 0x000002487C6CD2E0>
```

в примере ниже видно, что `__init__` необязательный метод, и атрибуты класса можно создавать где угодно и когда угодно, хотя это конечно и считается неправильным подходом

```
class A():
    def test(self):
        self.b = 123

a = A()
a.test()
print(a.b)  # 123
```

в примере ниже видно, что `self` это не ключевое слово, это просто обычный аргумент у метода и его общепринятое название, но это аргумент который идет первым, ничто не мешает нам назвать его иначе, хотя это конечно и считается неправильным подходом

```
class A():
    def __init__(qwerty):
        qwerty.b = 123

a = A()
print(a.b)  # 123
```

в примере ниже видно, что в исходном классе `A`, все его методы print(A.test) это обычные функции (function), которые лежат в области видимоcти `A`, а все методы его объекта `a` print(a.test) это методы(method), которые лежат в новой области видимости `a`,
причем эти методы, это просто специально "декорированные" исходные функции объекта `A` `print(a.test.__func__)`, "декорирование" которых придает функционал необязательности указания первого аргумента self при вызове методов как a.test(123), причем нам ничего не мешает обращаться к методу и через исходную функцию A.test(a, 123), но уже передавая первый аргумент self

```
class A():
    b = 321

    def test(self, v):
        print(v)

print(A.test)  # <function A.test at 0x000002AC72E35F70>
a = A()
print(a.test)  # <bound method A.test of <__main__.A object at 0x000002AC72FE5790>>
print(a.test.__func__)  # <function A.test at 0x000002AC72E35F70>

a.test(123)  # 123
A.test(a, 123)  # 123
```